# Internet Connection for Ubuntu 18.04 set up using Hyper-V

Tags: 18.04

I set up a VM running 18.04 using Windows 10 and the Hyper-V program, and I can't seem to get any sort of internet connection set up, wifi or wired. My Windows computer has Wi-Fi connected and I've shared it with a Network Switch through Hyper-V but it never shows up or connects in the Ubuntu machine. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: is Hyper-V something you want or just the first thing you found? because running ubuntu on windows is best accomplished with virtualbox which is free. You'll have have to fix your Hyper-V settings you configured it wrong there. as soon as there is an operable conection ubuntu will pick it up and use it automatically.

Comment: why is virtual box preferable to Hyper-V? what settings would need to be configured

Comment: because it's click and play. all I know is that I download the virtualbox installer and the ubuntu iso. run virtualbox, tell it new vm, insert the iso into the VM's drives in configuration and then start the VM and everything works out of the box. yes, including internet.