# Disable Internet connection for Ubuntu VM on Windows-10 Hyper-V

Tags: networking, 20.04, virtualization, hyper-v

I just installed latest version `20.04` of `Ubuntu` on `Hyper-V` of my `Windows-10`. During setup process I probably chose some setting that enabled the internet access to the VM. **Question**: How can I now disable the internet access to this VM?

There is only one `Virtual Switch` (that is default) for this VM as shown below. And, on this switch the connection type `Internal` is enabled (that, I thought, means) only the host machine and VMs inside hyper-v can connect each other. Also, as shown below, all the options are greyed out - that means you cannot make any changes here. So, I am not clear as to how to disable the internet connection from this VM. I am not sure why even the VM has access to the internet since the `External` connection type is not checked - as shown below. As explained in step-3 of this [official doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines#create-a-virtual-switch-by-using-hyper-v-manager) from Microsoft, only the `External` connection type allows access to external network. I have verified by using the default browser (Firefox) of the VM that VM can connect to the internet (which I don't want to happen):

[image]

**Remark**: My online search so far has shown only the issues of not being able to connect to the internet (such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1145040/1192231) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1157829/1192231)). My issue is in the opposite direction - I want to disable the internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the options are disabled because the VM is running. Shut it down, then try again.

Comment: I tried it with VM shut down, and the options are still greyed out (disabled).

Comment: If you use "new virtual switch", too?

Comment: With "new virtual switch", obviously all three [`External`, `Internal`, and `Private`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines#create-a-virtual-switch-by-using-hyper-v-manager) are available. But that does not help because if I create an `Internal` network switch the internet is still accessible from the VM - probably because VM is still using the default switch (which as the image above shows is also internal).

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt, as I'm assuming windows behavior based on the terms they use. On other setups external means you get directly mapped onto an `external` device, and `internal` means you have a SW-bridge on your host. Not if on that bridge (e.g. the Host itself) is a proper router the guest could access the net through that. You might want to take a look in your Ubuntu guest for a) which network got assigned is it dhcp from your router (external) or a virtual network with your host b) what gateway is set and if it is your host could/would you stop it from being a proper gateway?